Can I disable 'Edit Links'
I have an Excel workbook with links to other Excel files. I need to prevent other users from being able to look at the linked files (which they can do in the workbook Links pane).
Can I disable that pane or otherwise prevent them from looking at the linked files?

This is programming related site, not helpdesk.

Yes you can. Install the Office RibbonX Editor from here:
https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor/releases/tag/v1.9.0
Open the program and open your Excel file.
Insert an "Office 2010+ CustomUI" part and paste in this XML:
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <commands>
        <command idMso="EditLinks" enabled="false"/>
        <command idMso="WorkbookLinks" enabled="false"/>        
    </commands>
</customUI>

